# Need rotation matrix for opengl 3D transformation

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, transformation

The problem is I have two points in 3D space where y+ is up, x+ is to the right, and z+ is towards you. I want to orientate a cylinder between them that is the length of of the distance between both points, so that both its center ends touch the two points. I got the cylinder to translate to the location at the center of the two points, and I need help coming up with a rotation matrix to apply to the cylinder, so that it is orientated the correct way. My transformation matrix for the entire thing looks like this:

translate(center point) * rotateX(some X degrees) * rotateZ(some Z degrees)

The translation is applied last, that way I can get it to the correct orientation before I translate it.

Here is what I have so far for this:

```
mat4 getTransformation(vec3 point, vec3 parent)
{
    float deltaX = point.x - parent.x;
    float deltaY = point.y - parent.y;
    float deltaZ = point.z - parent.z;

    float yRotation = atan2f(deltaZ, deltaX) * (180.0 / M_PI);
    float xRotation = atan2f(deltaZ, deltaY) * (180.0 / M_PI);
    float zRotation = atan2f(deltaX, deltaY) * (-180.0 / M_PI);
    if(point.y < parent.y)
    {
        zRotation = atan2f(deltaX, deltaY) * (180.0 / M_PI);
    }

    vec3 center = vec3((point.x + parent.x)/2.0, (point.y + parent.y)/2.0, (point.z + parent.z)/2.0);
    mat4 translation = Translate(center);
    return translation * RotateX(xRotation) * RotateZ(zRotation) * Scale(radius, 1, radius) * Scale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
}
```

I tried a solution given down below, but it did not seem to work at all

```
mat4 getTransformation(vec3 parent, vec3 point)
{
    // moves base of cylinder to origin and gives it unit scaling
    mat4 scaleFactor = Translate(0, 0.5, 0) * Scale(radius/2.0, 1/2.0, radius/2.0) * cylinderModel;

    float length = sqrtf(pow((point.x - parent.x), 2) + pow((point.y - parent.y), 2) + pow((point.z - parent.z), 2));
    vec3 direction = normalize(point - parent);
    float pitch = acos(direction.y);
    float yaw = atan2(direction.z, direction.x);

    return Translate(parent) * Scale(length, length, length) * RotateX(pitch) * RotateY(yaw) * scaleFactor;
}
```

After running the above code I get this:
[image]

Every black point is a point with its parent being the point that spawned it (the one before it) I want the branches to fit into the points. Basically I am trying to implement the space colonization algorithm for random tree generation. I got most of it, but I want to map the branches to it so it looks good. I can use GL_LINES just to make a generic connection, but if I get this working it will look so much prettier. The algorithm is explained [here](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/colonization.egwnp2007.large.pdf).

Here is an image of what I am trying to do (pardon my paint skills)

[image]

Comment: Please note that one degree of freedom is missing: the roll of the cylinder around its own axis. Seeing your abstract formula, I guess you don't care which angle this will be. (Which is just fine, I just wanted to inform you that there are other possibilities to orient a cylinder between two points.)

Comment: Can you give me some hints on other possibilities? I have been trying to orientate this correctly since 11 am CMT lol

Comment: I only mean that your original goal description leaves an infinite number of solutions (in the mathematical sense, not how to program it). The idea you have is probably the easiest solution because it does *not* have this degree of freedom.

Comment: Do you want the matrix, or those two rotations?

Comment: The rotateX and rotateY methods return a 4x4 matrix. I am trying to get either it is just not clicking

Comment: Do you know how to use `acos2`?

Comment: Have you tried tackling a simpler problem first? Like the 2D problem?

Comment: yah got the 2d just fine

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's an arbitrary number of rotation matrices satisfying your constraints. But any will do. Instead of trying to figure out a specific rotation, we're just going to write down the matrix directly. Say your cylinder, when no transformation is applied, has its axis along the Z axis. So you have to transform the local space Z axis toward the direction between those two points. I.e. `z_t = normalize(p_1 - p_2)`, where `normalize(a) = a / length(a)`.

Now we just need to make this a full 3 dimensional coordinate base. We start with an arbitrary vector that's not parallel to z_t. Say, one of (1,0,0) or (0,1,0) or (0,0,1); use the scalar product `·`(also called inner, or dot product) with z_t and use the vector for which the absolute value is the smallest, let's call this vector `u`.
In pseudocode:

```
# Start with (1,0,0)
mindotabs = abs( z_t · (1,0,0) )
minvec = (1,0,0)
for u_ in (0,1,0), (0,0,1):
    dotabs = z_t · u_
    if dotabs < mindotabs:
        mindotabs = dotabs
        minvec = u_

u = minvec_
```

Then you *orthogonalize* that vector yielding a local y transformation `y_t = normalize(u - z_t · u)`.

Finally create the x transformation by taking the cross product `x_t = z_t × y_t`

To move the cylinder into place you combine that with a matching translation matrix.

Transformation matrices are effectively just the axes of the space you're "coming from" written down as if seen from the other space. So the resulting matrix, which is the rotation matrix you're looking for is simply the vectors x_t, y_t and z_t side by side as a matrix. OpenGL uses so called homogenuous matrices, so you have to pad it to a 4×4 form using a 0,0,0,1 bottommost row and rightmost column.

That you can load then into OpenGL; if using fixed functio using glMultMatrix to apply the rotation, or if using shader to multiply onto the matrix you're eventually pass to glUniform.

Comment: I am kind of confused with what u is in paragraph 2. I also am not getting what you mean by "the vector for which the absolute value is the smallest." What vectors are we referring to here?

Answer (score 0):

Begin with a unit length cylinder which has one of its ends, which I call `C1`, at the origin (note that your image indicates that your cylinder has its *center* at the origin, but you can easily transform that to what I begin with). The other end, which I call `C2`, is then at `(0,1,0)`.

I'd like to call your two points in world coordinates `P1` and `P2` and we want to locate `C1` on `P1` and `C2` to `P2`.

Start with translating the cylinder by `P1`, which successfully locates `C1` to `P1`.

Then scale the cylinder by `distance(P1, P2)`, since it originally had length `1`.

The remaining rotation can be computed using spherical coordinates. If you're not familiar with this type of coordinate system: it's like GPS coordinates: two angles; one around the pole axis (in your case the world's Y-axis) which we typically call *yaw*, the other one is a *pitch* angle (in your case the X axis in model space). These two angles can be computed by converting `P2-P1` (i.e. the local offset of `P2` with respect to `P1`) into spherical coordinates. First rotate the object with the pitch angle around X, then with yaw around Y.

Something like this will do it (pseudo-code):

```
Matrix getTransformation(Point P1, Point P2) {
    float length = distance(P1, P2);
    Point direction = normalize(P2 - P1);
    float pitch = acos(direction.y);
    float yaw = atan2(direction.z, direction.x);

    return translate(P1) * scaleY(length) * rotateX(pitch) * rotateY(yaw);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and my code for it is above, but it did not seem to have an effect.

Comment: In your updated code, use `Scale(radius, length, radius)` instead of `Scale(length, length, length)`. What do you see? I guess nothing from which you see what's wrong. Then try to play with the order. And try to do one step after another. First try to position the cylinder at `parent`, then scale it by the length (and if this fails, probably because of the wrong matrix order) and so on. It's so easy to get the order wrong!

Comment: I posted kind of what I am trying to do above if that helps

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. I assume that the problem is the order of transformations and / or the rotation axes. The formulas to deduce the angles should be correct, but you might want to double-check them too. My answer should only give you the idea, no 100% correct final code.

Comment: I took the formulas from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), but assume `r=1` and use `atan2` instead of `atan`.

Comment: Yah I feel it is close. The image above was got after converted the angles to degrees from the radians they are in since my Rotate() methods take degrees. I have tried order swapping the pitch and yaw but no luck.

Comment: Why do you use degrees? To generate these matrices you surely use `sin` and `cos`, which are in radians. I'd advice to use radians everywhere in your code base except for user input angles.

Comment: I am using a library that uses degrees. I just go with it since it is a simple conversion and it saves me time.

Answer (score 0):

Call the axis of the cylinder **A**. The second rotation (about **X**) can't change the angle between **A** and **X**, so we have to get that angle right with the *first* rotation (about **Z**).

Call the destination vector (the one between the two points) **B**. Take -acos(B<sub>X</sub>/B<sub>Y</sub>), and that's the angle of the first rotation.

Take **B** again, ignore the **X** component, and look at its projection in the (Y, Z) plane. Take acos(B<sub>Z</sub>/B<sub>Y</sub>), and that's the angle of the second rotation.